# Cannot start the terminal emulator 'xterm' on OS X Lion

Tags: qt, qt4, osx-lion

I get `Cannot start the terminal emulator 'xterm'`   error message when i try to build a Plain C++ Project. How to avoid this error ?!

Comment: How are you building the project? Are you using Qt Creator? Command line?

Comment: @NicholasSmith i'm using Qt Creator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go into Qt Creators preferences, then to Environment you can set the Terminal choice to whichever you need. Xterm *should* be supported under Lion however it is an X11 application so you'll need to have the X11 environment installed, which is on the Apple Developer Tools installer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install xterm. In my CentOs, on command line, run: yum install xterm. Then run QCreator again.